# Debugging stored procedures in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: debugging, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2012

Has anybody used Visual Studio 2012 to debug a stored procedure?

I am trying to do so. I have opened the view `Server Explorer` and created *new connection to the database* and selected my database.

Now if I go the stored procedure that I want to debug and right click I can't see the option **Step into stored procedure**! It should be there!

However I can put breakpoints inside the stored procedure. But if I run the code which uses that procedure the breakpoint won't get hit!

Any idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use the SQL Server Object Explorer, not the Server Explorer. Unfortunate confluence of names.